# How to set single picker view for different button actions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I have three different buttons. When I click those buttons, it shows a picker view. I am using the same picker view each time, but the rows in the picker view should be different depending on which button was pressed.

How do I make the picker view display the rows I want, depending on which button was pressed?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use the UIPickerView and the delegate for that pickerView is the same viewController as where you buttons are.
I would create 4 arrays, 3 for each button with the values to show in the picker and 1 array that is used by `– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`

```
NSArray *pickerData;
NSArray *button1Data;
NSArray *button2Data;
NSArray *button3Data;
```

Then in the IBActions of the buttons (or you set the target and selector in code)

```
- (IBAction)button1Action:(id)sender {
    [pickerData release];
    pickerData = [button1Data retain];
}

- (IBAction)button2Action:(id)sender {
    [pickerData release];
    pickerData = [button2Data retain];
}

etc...
```

And in `– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` you use pickerData to display your values

I hope this makes sence